# I want to make Date file to run Command line in CMD

Tags: cmd, command

I am always running a command by using Command prompt with run as administrator.

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
enter
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
enter
```

so please how can I make dat file where I just click and this command line automatically run with administrator

Answer (score 0):

```
Create files on your computer such as DONETSTOP.bat and DONETSTART.bat
Create a shortcut to each of them on your desktop
Select one of the shortcuts
Press Alt-Enter Choose the "Advanced" button
Check the "Run as administrator" checkbox
Do this for the other shortcut
Double click on either of these shortcuts to run them.
```